# How to loop through json data and need only data under RED

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, loops

Here is data I have. I want to loop through all the data under `Registered_Courses.RED` and display it in reactjs.

```
[
  {
    RED: [
      {
        course_Name: 'Programming Fundamentals',
        course_Code: 'SODV110',
        start_Date: '2021-10-10',
        end_Date: '2022-10-11',
        Fees: '$1300',
        Delivery_Mode: 'In Class Learning',
        Description: 'Computer programming is central to software development.',
      },
      {
        course_Name: 'Programming Fundamentals',
        course_Code: 'SODV110',
        start_Date: '2021-10-10',
        end_Date: '2022-10-11',
        Fees: '$1300',
        Delivery_Mode: 'In Class Learning',
        Description: 'Computer programming is central to software development.',
      },
    ],
    NESS: [
      {
        course_Name: 'Programming Fundamentals',
        course_Code: 'SODV110',
        start_Date: '2021-10-10',
        end_Date: '2022-10-11',
        Fees: '$1300',
        Delivery_Mode: 'In Class Learning',
        Description: 'Computer programming is central to software development.',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Registered_Courses.RED.forEach(function() {
    // code
});
```

I believe this should work